# How is the merchant spending cap determined?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Man, it sucks that Tonilia (the Fence) only has 1000 gold at a time. It's very tedious to only sell 1000 septims worth of stuff at a time. I don't want to put perks in Speech just to sell stuff faster. Can't I just cheat to give her more septims with which to buy my <1000-value crap and just pretend that I had grinded?
(prid 000b882a (Tonilia)) "additem 000000f [gold amount]". Hey, she only gives up to 19454 septims. Beyond that, I can sell my stuff, but we don't trade gold for it despite the counter showing that she still has gold left. Hey, this time she only gave 16960. When I give her 99999 gold, she doesn't even give anything. What's the deal? What determines how much a merchant will spend? Why does it seem random?

Comment: Why don't you just give yourself the gold and remove the items (or keep them, I won't tell anyone)?

Comment: @5pike I thought of that, but I have so many items that it'd be tedious to calculate the total, and I wouldn't get Speech XP that way.

Comment: I think you can also give yourself skill xp via a command, but I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merchant spending cap seems to be a signed 16-bit [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types), therefore the maximum value is 32,767.

Much kudos to kotekzot's [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/156021/46216) for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Does this actually answers your question? I thought the underlying question was what to do about the little gold fences and vendors have. Yet this only clarifies in what datatype the gold amount gets stored, how the variable behind this int gets filled, which is actually the question as it stands in the title does not get answered by merely saying that it gets stored as an int.

Comment: Hm, well I was mostly just wondering what the maximum was, if there was one, hence "cap". I didn't know the limit was due to the integer nature. If I were asking your question, I'd rephrase it as: How do I increase merchant gold? So I admit that my question is rather narrow, applying mainly to PC users who either make mods that affect merchant gold or use the console to change merchant gold amount.

Answer (score 5):

Merchants will become buggy if they have over 30000 gold. Make sure not to give her so much gold that the total amount exceeds 30k.

Comment: Ah, I think I know the limit! I was messing with numbers around 30000 and I think I know what it is: It's probably 32767 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types

Comment: @NiteCyper: That fits with her not giving anything at 99999 gold, because that becomes a negative number after 16-bit overflow.

Comment: @NiteCyper is your question answered or do you need some other piece of information?

Comment: @kotekzot I was conflicted with deciding to answer my own question with the more specific answer that I found when your answer helped so much, but I suppose that you don't need the rep and you'll be credited. That, and I couldn't accept my own answer so soon after posting the question. Although, I just realized that the time limit is based on when I post the answer, not the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a mod to increase vendors and fences money. There are many mods to choose from, some just add a certain amount or make it infinite like the ["more gold in stores and merchants"](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/35609/?) mod.

For more immersion i suggest you install this mod: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=14024. It increases the gold depending on your level.